# What are all of the possible endings?

Tags: indiana-jones-fate-of-atlantis

So far I have managed to pull off the following endings:

1. Trick the scientist into experimenting on himself - where you escape with Sofia
2. Trick the scientist into experimenting on himself but have Sofia intervene - you escape alone
3. Turn yourself into a god - obviously a bad ending

From what I can tell, having Sofia in the room with you or not gives the same outcome for the third ending listed above.

Are these the only endings?

Have I missed any?

**Update**

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Fate_of_Atlantis:

> Three bad endings see one of the protagonists undergo the second transformation if Indiana could not convince Ubermann to use the machine instead, or if Sophia was not freed from her prison or Nur-Ab-Sal's influence. In the good ending, Atlantis succumbs to the eruption of the still active volcano as the duo flees from the city. The final scene depicts Indiana kissing Sophia on top of the escape submarine, to comfort himself for the lack of evidence for their discovery.

This doesn't really tally up with my experience/interpretation.

Comment: Doesn't Sofia always come with you in the last section of the game?

Comment: @Powerlord She is locked up in Atlantis, but you can choose to either not rescue her from the cell.  Also, if you choose to rescue her you can leave her possessed (in this state she won't follow you into the last area).  Being possessed or locked up can lead to endings 2 or 3 from my experience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting to track down all of the possible endings through the power of Google and play testing the final Atlantis area in the game, I can only see 3 possible endings.

You can reach the final room in 2 states:

1. With Sophia (by letting her out of the cage and then taking her necklace)
2. Without Sophia (leaving her in the cage OR letting her keep her necklace)

After Kerner dies from the first experiment you can either let Hans use the machine on you, or trick him into using the machine on himself.

**Good Ending**

Conditions:

1. Sophia is with Indy
2. Indy tricks Hans

Outcomes:

1. Hans will transform
2. Indy and Sophia escape together

**Alternative Ending**

Conditions:

1. Sophia is NOT with Indy
2. Indy tricks Hans

Outcomes:

1. Sophia will intervene
2. Sophia will transform
3. Indy will escape alone

**Bad Ending**

Conditions:

1. Indy participates in the experiment

*It doesn't matter whether Sophia is present or not*

Outcomes:

1. Indy transforms

I assume that confusion from other sources surrounds the interpretation that having Sophia in the room or not for the "Bad Ending" can be seen as 2 different endings.

Comment: There's also another "ending" where you get caught in the U-Boat and Indy dies before even reaching Atlantis.